# Accepting multiple clients in python socket server

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to build a simple socket server in python:

```
import socket
import threading
import time


def handle(conn_addr):
  print("Someone Connected")
  time.sleep(4)
  print("And now I die")


host = ''
port = 5000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
  s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
  print(str(e))

s.listen(2)

while True:
  threading.Thread(handle(s.accept())).start()


print("Should never be reached")
```

The socket server should accept multiple clients at the same time. I tried to test its functionality by calling telnet localhost 5000 from multiple tabs from my shell however the pattern that i get is

```
Someone Connected
And now I die
Someone Connected
And now I die
```

Instead of

```
Someone Connected
Someone Connected
Someone Connected
```

I call the telnet command within 4 seconds of each other so it should have 2 messages of connected in a row however the message is only returned after the previous socket is disconnected. Why is that and how could I go round fixing this?

Comment: You are printing the die statement without closing the socket. The clients should still be connected

Comment: But why doesn't the function print "someone connected" as soon as I connect to it? It always waits for "die" to be printed ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should print "connected", then pause for 4 seconds, then print "die" (even though you don't close the socket). Is that not what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a classic mistake. You called `handle()` (which slept for 4 seconds) and then tried to create a thread from its result. The target should be a function reference and args should be passed separately.

```
threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(s.accept(),)).start()
```

In this version, the main thread waits for an `accept` and then creates the thread that runs `handle`.

Comment: This helped us in creating a delegation for the event socket.recv(1024) in python, @tdelaney, would you like to give feedback on that ? thanks.

Comment: @ArsalanSaleem - I'm not sure how that would work. `Thread(target=mysock.rec, args=(1024,)).start()` would be problematic. Where would the received data go to? `recv` may get anything from 0 to 1024 bytes (socket closed is 0, or since its byte oriented, only a partial message) and could get an Exception. I'd need the details to know. .... and that would be hard to put in a comment here. Perhaps a new question or maybe something on https://codereview.stackexchange.com?